# How to apply the formula $A^{-1}=D^{2}A^{T}$ to find $A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve exercises 6.3.5-8 from *Linear Algebra* (Fraleigh):

*If $A$ and $D$ are square matrices, $D$ is diagonal, and $AD$ is orthogonal, then $(AD)^{-1}=(AD)^{T}$ and $D^{-1}A^{-1}=D^{T}A^{T}$ so that $A^{-1}=DD^{T}A^{T}$. In Exercises 5-8, find the inverse of each matrix $A$ by first finding a diagonal matrix $D$ so that $AD$ has column vectors of length $1$, and then applying the formula $A^{-1}=D^{2}A^{T}$.*

Exercise 6.3.5 gives this matrix:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 3 \\ 
-1 && 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The first thing I tried to do was to compute the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ for finding a diagonal matrix $D$, but it does not has real eigenvalues.

Some ideas, suggestions to start solving it?

Comment: You are not trying to diagonalize the matrix $A$; the purpose of finding $D$ is so that $AD$ has column vectors of length 1, according to the hint.  Can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the columns of matrix $\bf{A}$ are already orthogonal (dot product = 0).

Thus, you only need to normalize each of these columns, by multiplying them resp. by $a=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{18}}$.

How can the operation be done "in a matrix way" ? By right multiplying by the diagonal matrix

$$ \bf{D} = \begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}$$

with values of $a,b$ above.

Rule: if $\bf{D}$=$diag(a_1,a_2,...)$, $\bf{AD}$ gives a multiplication of the columns of $A$ by $a_1, a_2, \cdots$, whereas $\bf{DA}$ does the same, but on the rows of $\bf{A}$.

Comment: $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}$

Comment: @ John Ortiz Ordoñez You are right. I correct it. Thanks !